# php empty page when using $_REQUEST

Tags: php

I just got started with php. I have a form in a web page that directs to handle.php, like this:

```
<form action = "handle.php" method="post">
    <p><b>name:</b> <input type = "text" name = "name" size="20"/><p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit my info">
</form>
```

In my `handle.php`, this is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Hello! </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo "<p>Name: $_REQUEST['name']<p>";
        ?>
        <p> Hi</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This page appears completely empty. Interestingly, if I remove `$_REQUEST['name']`, then everything is fine. Seems to me that calling `$_REQUEST` makes the page empty (i check the source code and theres nothing there).

What am I doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: echo "<p>Name: " . $_REQUEST['name'] . "<p>";

Comment: First thing to do: Adjust your error reporting settings for your development server! You need to set the PHP configuration flag display_errors to On!

Comment: That white page means that there is an error, which you will also find in your php error log.

Comment: ah wow, thanks. how come this works then? echo "<p>Name: $someVariable <p>";

Comment: Becuse in string ("") you can't access array. Well you can but like this: "<p>Name: $_REQUEST[name] <p>"

Comment: thanks man! understand what's going on now. also turned on the display_errors!

Comment: Please also use `$_GET` or `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`. The use of `$_REQUEST` opens you wide up to Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks, where an attacker essentially forges a user action. You should also be using `htmlspecialchars` to escape anything that comes from your user and is placed in the HTML. If you don't, they can inject HTML or JavaScript, which may pose security problems.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up Polynomial!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have error reporting off and you are receiving a fatal error, which is why you are not seeing anything. Inline variables can't be used the way you do it so try replacing your echo with this:

```
echo "<p>Name: ".$_REQUEST['name']."<p>";
```

or this:

```
echo "<p>Name: {$_REQUEST['name']}<p>";
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with this:

```
echo "<p>Name: " . $_REQUEST['name'] . "<p>";
```

You may also enable the error report in order to avoid situations like this. You can do this in the php.ini file or at the top of you PHP page: error_reporting(-1).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: ...or `echo "<p>Name: {$_REQUEST['name']}<p>";`

Answer (score 3):

Proper syntax:

```
echo "<p>Name: ".$_REQUEST['name']."<p>";
```

or

```
echo "<p>Name: {$_REQUEST['name']}<p>";
```

I really recommend you to read this documentation:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 2):

You should change your code to this:

```
echo "<p>Name: {$_REQUEST['name']}<p>";
```

You should take a look at the "complex curly syntax" section on the [PHP Manual string page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

And you should read how to [enable error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<p>Name: $_REQUEST[name]<p>";
```

Comment: I don't understand *quite* how it is that this answer is at present at +1/-0 while another answer saying exactly the same thing has +0/-6.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to echo an array-variable you need to kind of "escape" it like so:

```
<?php
    echo "<p>Name: {$_REQUEST['name']}<p>";
?>
```

Another solution is this:

```
<?php
    echo '<p>Name: '.$_REQUEST['name'].'<p>';
?>
```

Look up the diffrences between strings with `'` and strings with `"`

Answer (score 1):

I would guess your script is throwing a syntax error.

Try replacing this line

```
echo "<p>Name: $_REQUEST['name']<p>";
```

with

```
echo "<p>Name: {$_REQUEST['name']}<p>";
```

See the manual for [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) for info on how single- and double-quoted strings work.

In general, it's often a good idea on development sites to enable error reporting so the page displays errors like this rather than just "throwing a whitey". Make sure if you do, that displaying errors is disabled on production sites (although you might want to log errors still).

Answer (score 1):

What is probably happening is that you get a fatal error but the configuration of your php.ini in the section error_reporting just ignore it, this is why you get a white page. Change it to E_ALL or something like that to have an easier development!

Once you have an explicit error, if it is not still solved, post it here.

Answer (score 0):

*Repost of my previous answer, with the incorrect bit removed*

You didn't wrap the value in `{}` properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title> Hello! </title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <?php
        echo "<p>Name: {$_REQUEST['name']}<p>";
        ?>

        <p> Hi</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

You should also not use `$_REQUEST`, but rather `$_GET` and `$_POST`. It's generally a bad idea to get into the habit of using `$_REQUEST` because it can open up CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) attacks.

I would also suggest wrapping your user variable in `htmlspecialchars` to prevent them from being able to inject HTML or script into your page:

```
    <?php
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name']);
    echo "<p>Name: {$name}<p>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score -5):

```
replace this 
echo "<p>Name: $_REQUEST['name']<p>";

to 

echo "<p>Name: $_REQUEST[name]<p>";
```